# Need php code for a selection from database that's greater than 5 but not 15 (meaning all numbers higher than 5 not including 15)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, conditional-statements

Here is the code:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `groups` WHERE `id`>5 ORDER BY `name` ASC";
$results = mysql_query($q);
```

My problem is, I can adjust 'id'>5 to < or not equal, etc...but I want to display all groups that are numbered greater than 5 but NOT 15...so, any groups numbered 6, 10, 14, 22, 36, all fine....just not 15 or less than 5.

Any way to rewrite this $q line above to make that possible?

Comment: So it sounds like you really want a query, not PHP code. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi @MikeBrant, thank you, that's probably true.  I'm not well versed, but I juggle the code I have...this is the one part that's got me stuck!

Comment: By the way, I've searched and searched for this answer, but normally all that comes up is "greater than but not equal to" which is completely different.  Thank you again!

Comment: This is exactly the same as "greater than but not equal to".

Comment: Basically the difference is any number that is "greater than but not equal to" 5 is any number higher than five.  This is different...it's greater than but not equal to 5 as well as not 15 (which is also greater than but not equal to 5).

Comment: As a side note... you generally shouldn't be doing this with auto-generated ids, where the values are essentially meaningless.  Yes, it's often implemented simply by just increasing a count by one, but this doesn't tell you anything about how the data may have been updated for correction purposes.  You'd be better off using natural keys, if available; if somebody adds a new group having the same natural key that is causing `15` to be excluded, you need to modify this query.  If you're using the natural key, it automatically happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another condition in your WHERE clause

```
SELECT *
FROM `groups`
WHERE
  `id` > 5
  AND `id` <> 15
ORDER BY `name` ASC
```

Comment: thank you so much!  I feel like the biggest idiot. I swear I've tried that...but probably not...probably tried different combinations of <!=, etc...  I can't thank you enough for the quick response.  I'm fine in HTML, CSS, but this PHP (I assume) kills me!  THANK YOU!